# Instance start stuck with "PROVISIONING" status

Tags: google-compute-engine

Tried to start an instance using Developers Console. Received Error message:

```
Start VM instance "venus"
Code: '1426056560669-510FDAABA7149-018771D4-788FB15B'
```

Checked the status of the instance using gcloud...

```
gcloud compute instances list --project radiant-night-771
NAME    ZONE          MACHINE_TYPE  INTERNAL_IP    EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
venus   asia-east1-b  n1-highcpu-8  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx PROVISIONING
```

It is more than 30 minutes and the status is still "Provisioning".

What is the problem ?